# , и . в css при определении элементов класса

Tags: css

В чём отличия между

```
.elem-1, .elem-2 {}
```

и

```
.elem-1.elem-2 {}
```

В [документации](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/Reference#Selectors) я не нашёл первого примера.

Comment: на указанной странице найдите блок "Базовый синтаксис правил" и читайте определение `selectorList` до тех пор пока не увидите в нем ответ на вопрос.

Comment: @teran я не автор вопроса, но я тоже не вижу ответ в указанном месте

Comment: Атрибут класса определяется как разделенный пробелами список элементов, и один из этих пунктов должен точно соответствовать имени класса, приведенному в селекторе. (из ссылки)

Comment: https://learn.javascript.ru/css-selectors  тут получше объясняется

Comment: http://google.com/#q=css%20%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8B%20%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%8F

Comment: @andreymal `selectorlist {...}` и далее расшифровка `где selectorlist: selector[:pseudo-class] [::pseudo-element] [, more selectorlists]`, очевидно, ответ в концовке `[, more selectorlists]`?

Comment: @teran совершенно не очевидно, так как поведение всей этой дребедени не описано

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Свойства применяются к элементам содержащим классы elem1 или elem2, но могут содержать оба
2. Свойства применяются к элементам обязательно содержащим ОБА класса сразу